# Mono audio track on two speakers

Tags: audio, speakers

I have a mono audio signal which I want to output on two boxes. Can I just connect the speakers in series or parallel (which?) or do I have to do something more advanced (and if so, what)?

Comment: Please elaborate the term boxes in your context. Do you mean speakers?

Comment: Ah, right, it isn't an English term. We use it in The Netherlands all the time when we mean speakers. But thanks, I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually better to connect them in parallel, as speakers are best driven from a low impedance. However you need to check that the amplifier is up to the job of driving such a low impedance. If each speaker is 8 ohm impedance, the amplifier must be capable of driving 4 ohms.

Failing that, you can connect them in series but you may hear a difference in the quality of the bass.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you would have to use an output transformer to drive the speakers to match the impedance. You could use a multi-tap transformer.

In fact there is a US patent [Multiple output transformer network for sound reproducing system](http://www.google.com/patents/US5598480)

[image: driver]

But connecting them parallel in a jiffy should work for low wattage systems. Your PA should be tolerant also ;)

Comment: The drawing shows a crossover network, which solves an entirely different problem.

Comment: I couldn't find an image with identical filters at the end. Basically you have to match the impedance. Remove the LC filter at speaker end and it should work.

Comment: Yes you can impedance match using transformers as in the edited drawing. But it's highly unusual outside of vacuum tube amplifiers, 1960s transistor radios, and "100V" public address systems (where audio was distributed at high voltage to keep wiring losses down). Practically, it's cheaper to build an amplifier capable of driving 1 or 2 ohm loads.

Comment: @BrianDrummond true that individual PA can be used but OP wanted help on connecting to existing PA. BTW I have fixed the image.

Comment: It's worth noting that connecting identical speakers in series will cut the volume by 6dB but leave the sound otherwise unaffected; connecting non-identical speakers in series, however, may have weird effects on the two speakers' frequency response.  The fraction of energy which goes into each speaker will depend upon how its impedance compares with the other.  Since most speakers have an impedance which varies significantly with frequency, and different speakers vary differently, this will cause the balance of power between non-matched speakers to likewise vary.